# My system sound in Swift is not played

Tags: swift, ios9

This what I use:

```
if let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Aurora", ofType: "aiff") {

    //it doesn't gets here
    let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
    var soundID:SystemSoundID = 0
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(fileURL, &soundID)
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID)
}
```

How to do this? I've read a lot about this, but nothing has worked.

Testing on a real device.

Comment: If it does not get your code to play sound, it sure that the sound is not played. Verify if the file named Aurora.aiff is included in the bundle :)

Comment: Ok, how to verify is it exist in the bundle? I just get the name from the setting in iDevice.

Comment: From your xcode project, select the audio file, then verify in the right menu if the file is selected for your application (in "Target Membership" section). If yes, the file must be found when you call NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
func getSoundID() -> SystemSoundID {
  var soundID: SystemSoundID = 0
  let soundURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), "Glass", "mp3", nil)
  AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundURL, &soundID)
  return soundID
}

let soundId: SystemSoundID = playSound()
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundId)
```

You can also check your system is playing the sound or not by putting sound ID as follows:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1200)
```

Please also check the value of the system.